# problema de query Mysql (subquery) diferença entre versões MYSQL.

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou com um problema em uma consulta de MYSQL, creio que seja diferença de versões do MYSQL, o banco de meu cliente está no hostGator **(Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73 / Server version: 5.6.30 - MySQL Community Server )** , fiz um backup do banco e coloquei no meu servidor na Locahost **(Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.50 / Server version: 5.1.73-rel14.11-log )**.

Minha query é esta:

```
select pp.id as id_promocao, pv.id as id_vigencia, pp.titulo, pp.descricao, 
DATE_FORMAT(pv.data_inicial,'%d/%m/%y - %h:%i h') as data_inicial, 
 DATE_FORMAT(pv.data_final,'%d/%m/%y - %h:%i h') as data_final
from promocoes_promocao pp 
inner join promocoes_vigencia pv on pv.promocao_id = pp.id  
where pp.ativo = 1 and pv.data_final >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
and pv.id in (select p.id  
                from promocoes_vigencia p  
                where  p.data_final >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR) 
                group by p.promocao_id) 
order by pv.data_final
```

no servidor do cliente (hostgator) me retorna 23 linhas já no meu servidor que é o correto me retornam 4 linhas.

consegui identificar que o problema está na subselect, peguei apenas os valores da subselect e coloquei os valores 4 valores e funcionou não tive problema.

** para entender o que eu estou fazendo com a subselect eu tenho uma tabela que tem promocoes_vigencia com duas datas (inicial e final) e Id_promocao (fk) e uma outra tabela com o nome de **promocoes_promocao** campo Id (pk). 
o problema é que a tabela promocoes_vigencia tem varias promoções ja cadastras, para o mesmo cliente eu tenho que pegar apenas 1 registro de cada destas vigencias dentro da data inicial e final. 
ex.

Tabela  **promocoes_vigencia**

[image: exemplo é o código 635]

Nesta linha eu preciso pegar apenas o min(data_final) and data_inicial > now

Tabela **promocoes_promocao**

[image: Tabela promocao]

tenho uma unica promocao em varias datas diferentes.

Alguma sugestão para este problema?

Comment: Você conferiu a diferença de horário entre os servidores?

Comment: sim a diferença é de 3 horas.